SharePoint 2016 on prem copy and pasting
I'm new to SP and working with an SharePoint (SP) on prem 2016 instance.
I'm using Windows 11, and have Chrome and Bing browsers with no plugins available.
I'd like to be able to import data from excel, but the app available requires Active-X controls, I do not have any old browsers that support Active-X, so this is a dead end.
Searching the above problem quickly tells me to try copy/pasting data, which seems like a good enough solution, however this also fails.
I can paste from excel to excel and from SP to SP, but not between the two.  I can enable viewing the clipboard and see the data in the clipboard, and when I copy from SP the data on the (windows) clipboard is not updated.  eg. when I cntr-c on SP, then cntr-c in excel, then cntl-v in SP, the data I copied from SP is pasted.  Conversely cntr-c in excel, then cntr-c in SP, then cntr-v in excel, and the data from excel is pasted.  It's like there are two separate clipboards.
I feel like someone is messing with me.  I have full admin privileges and could write a program to import, but that isn't the easiest solution either.
Any reasonable workaround suggestions?   Do others have this problem?
